# How can i center the content of a WebView?

Tags: java, android, html, css, webview

A part of my app loads an image into a WebView from a URL.
Using the following settings for the WebView:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Relevant part from the layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem with this, if the image if smaller in height than the screen, it appears aligned to the top of the WebView.

Is it possible to align it to the center?

I tried the following, but it just doesn't work all the time, no idea why.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

edit:
Tried the following with CSS, still doesn't work (the image is displayed, but not centered vertically).

```
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<html><head><style>img {margin-top:auto;margin-bottom:auto}</style></head><body><img src=\"" + url + "\"></body></html>", "html/css", "utf-8", null);
```

edit2:
Bojan Kseneman's solution is working. I was using

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize
```

that's why it seemed to be wrong at first. Removed this line from my `Manifest.xml` fixed the problems (handling `onSaveInstanceState` is of course necessary in this case).

Comment: You can center the image vertically and horizontally within webview by using CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tried this but doesn't seem to work. Code is in my original post. (used margin-top and margin-bottom, because i'd like to center vertically, not horizontally)

Comment: See my edit. I though you need it horizontally aligned.

Comment: Thanks, tried it, seems to work, but only in portrait mode and only after an orientation-change. So it's still aligned at the top initially, i switch to landscape, back to portrait and it's centered correctly.